# ¿Cómo traducir "airbender" al español?

Tags: traducción, inglés, concurso-de-popularidad

Llevaba un tiempo oyendo hablar de la serie *[Avatar: The last airbender](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0417299/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)* como una serie de animación muy buena que ver. Cuando me puse a buscarla encontré que en Netflix estaba una llamada *Avatar: La leyenda de Aang*. Pensaba que se trataba de alguna continuación, o serie derivada, pero resultó que no, que eran la misma serie, solo que en España le habían dado ese nombre.

Entiendo que la razón fue la dificultad por encontrar una traducción con gancho para *airbender*, dado que *doblador del aire* no suena muy bien. De hecho en la serie en su versión original, a las personas que pueden manipular los elementos tal y como se refleja en la misma los llaman *benders*: *earthbender*, *firebender*, *waterbender* y *airbender*. En la versión al español han optado por "maestros": maestro del agua, del fuego, del aire y del viento. Estas personas pueden hacer que cada uno de los elementos se moldee y se comporte como ellos quieren: pueden hacer que el viento sople como quieran, que el agua forme remolinos a voluntad, lanzar bolas de fuego, levantar muros de piedra al instante, etc.

A ver, no es mala opción. Entre las definiciones de *[maestro](https://dle.rae.es/maestro)* podemos encontrar "persona que es práctica en una materia y la maneja con desenvoltura". De ahí, un "maestro del agua" sería una persona que maneja el agua con desenvoltura", pero me falta ese toque de fantasía, de irrealidad, de que en realidad lo que hace esa persona no es usar el agua, sino manipularla a su antojo y voluntad. De ahí el original *bender* que da la sensación de personas que "doblan la realidad".

Así pues, concurso al canto. ¿Qué opción se os ocurre para traducir *airbender* (o *bender* en general) para que se respete ese toque de fantasía y de manipulación de los elementos, y que al mismo tiempo tenga gancho y suene bien como título de una serie? Como de costumbre, y dado el carácter subjetivo de la pregunta, se aceptará la respuesta más votada al cabo de una semana.

Comment: Yo iba a aportar _aeromante_, _piromante_ y otros parecidos, pero investigando las fuentes he visto que el sufijo *-mante* significa "adivinación por medio de", por lo que un *aeromante* sería alguien que realiza una "adivinación supersticiosa por las señales e impresiones del aire". Iba a intentar forzarlo un poco, alegando que en el stack tenemos la medalla de *necromante/necromancer* con el sentido que se hace de ella en los juegos y novelas de fantasía (*alzar o controlar* a los muertos, más que adivinar a través de ellos, que también) pero creo que no me llega y lo dejo como comentario.

Comment: @Diego Pues por mi parte vas por buen camino, porque yo también he considerado la opción de combinar los prefijos _aero-_, _piro-_, _hidro-_ y _geo-_ con algún sustantivo. Después de darle muchas vueltas a lo más que he llegado es a _aeronauta_, pero eso da la sensación de que usa el viento para navegar. O también _aerómano_, en el sentido de "aficionado con pasión", pero _pirómano_ tiene otras connotaciones. Aún estoy buscando.

Comment: A mi "aeroista" me suena muy feo pero "El sufijo -ista se añade a substantivos y también a adjetivos y verbos para formar nombres y adjetivos llanos concretos que denotan profesión, oficio, hábito u ocupación." No sé si podemos encontrar algo del latín o griego con el significado de "manipular, moldear, modelar" que tiene ese "bender" en inglés.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se puede sugerir

> Avatar, el último ***mago***, amo del aire

siendo que en su definición [mago](https://dle.rae.es/mago?m=form) presupone una destreza o maestría especial

> 2. m. y f. Persona singularmente capacitada para el éxito en una actividad determinada. Es un mago de las finanzas.

En la misma tesitura cabría

> Avatar, el último ***artista*** del aire
>
> [artista](https://dle.rae.es/artista?m=form) 
> 5. m. y f. Persona que hace algo con suma perfección

Puestos a crear también puede pensarse en

> ***amo***, (o) 
> ***domador*** del aire

y acaso

> **Avatar, el último ***encantador*** aereo**

que traduce quizás mejor la naturaleza de su arte sutil, por cuanto [encantar](https://dle.rae.es/encantar) es

> 1. tr. Someter a poderes mágicos.
> 2. tr. Atraer o ganar la voluntad de alguien por dones naturales, como la hermosura, la gracia, la simpatía o el talento.

Comment: tomando parcialmente prestada la buena sugerencia de @wimi

Comment: Juntando tu respuesta y los comentarios de Diego y Charlie a la pregunta, se podría incluso sugerir "aeromago"...

Comment: Interesante, ¡suena bien!

Comment: @wimi de hecho _aeromago_, _piromago_, _hidromago_ y _terramago_ fueron también una de las opciones que pensé. Las descarté simplemente porque en la serie no se habla de "magia", el manipular los elementos no se toma como tal, sino como algo natural que pueden hacer determinadas personas. Pero la verdad es que suena bien, así que si lo quieres añadir a tu respuesta...

Comment: @Charlie lo he añadido a mi respuesta. Sin embargo, no puedo evitar pensar que poca parte de la idea es mía (he combinado la respuesta de ipp con tu comentario), así que podéis quitar esa parte de mi respuesta, o hacerla "community wiki" si pensáis que no es suficientemente "original".

Comment: ¡Ganadora por votación popular!

Answer (score 3):

Sé que esta publicación es de hace años pero acabo de empezar a ver La leyenda de Korra y me he preguntado lo mismo.

Yo propondría usar "-dinamista". El que se dedica al estudio o la práctica del movimiento y la fuerza de algo.

Aerodinamista, Geodinamista, Hidrodinamista y Pirodinamista.

También he decir que si usan ¨maestro¨ sería mejor como sufijo. Geomaestro, Hidromaestro, Piromaestro y Aeromaestro.

Es un tema curioso desde luego.

Comment: Tiene sentido, proviene de *δύναμις*, *dynamis*, que significa ‘potencia’ o ‘fuerza’ impulsora. No está mal, pero me sigo quedando con la respuesta aceptada

Answer (score 1):

Se podría decir *[moldeador](https://dle.rae.es/moldeador)*, que es la persona que [moldea](https://dle.rae.es/moldear), es decir, que

> 4. tr. [da] forma a algo material o inmaterial.

El título sería pues "El último moldeador del aire". Esta palabra se ajusta quizá algo mejor al significado de la palabra inglesa *bender*, pero probablemente tiene menos puntos en el criterio de que "tenga gancho y suene bien como título de una serie".

Combinando la [sugerencia de ipp](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/35775/24236) (*mago*) con el comentario de Charlie en su pregunta (usar el prefijo griego *aero-*), se me ocurre también

- El último aeromago

que me suena algo mejor para el título de una serie.

Comment: ¿El título entonces podría ser "El último moldeador del aire"?

Comment: @Charlie sí, lo he hecho explícito en la respuesta. Espero que aparezcan otras sugerencias con más gancho.

Answer (score 0):

Reconozco que no suena muy artístico, la verdad, pero sugiero:

> El retorcedor del aire

dado que [**torcer**](https://dle.rae.es/torcer) es, entre otras cosas

> Mover bruscamente un miembro u otra cosa, contra el orden natural.

Answer (score -1):

Doblar es una forma de moldear, pero es mas que eso... ellos manejan el aire. No suena lindo... pero sería de una forma mas amplia que incluye "maestría" en manejar algo. "Manejador del aire" lo que deriva en mas que una traducción en una interpretación y ante eso la interpretación mas adecuada es la usada... "maestro del aire"... ✌